# Displaying a non associative array

Tags: php, arrays

Most articles about displaying an array in PHP seem to be for associative arrays. Is there a better way to display a non associative array than the following ?

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $my_array ); $i ++ ) {
    echo $my_array[$i]; 
}
```

Comment: I still prefer to use a `for` loop when I'm dealing with a numerical array - I know this technically doesn't exist in PHP but then surely this is an argument *"for"* re-enforcing the idea of one?

Comment: @Emissary Are you confused with associative arrays not technically existing in Javascript?

Comment: @nl-x nope -> [first sentence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($my_array as $val)
    echo $val;
```

Answer (score 4):

The way you're looping is just fine. However, I prefer to use `foreach` in `php`:

```
$array = array("1", "anotherItem", "more data");

foreach($array as $value){
   echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's depends on what is the purpose of the display. If you just want to peek its content for debugging purposes then plain `print_r()` or `var_dump()` would suffice. Otherwise just loop as you do.

Comment: Also wrap the var_dump or print_r into HTML's <pre></pre> and you will be very happy ^.^ front almost accurate formatted output

Answer (score 0):

and

```
echo implode("", $my_array);
```

"" being what is used as glue. (For example, try "<br/>\n")

Comment: I think if you want to simply *display* the array, you should stick to  `print_r` or `var_dump`

Comment: Right, I'm simply suggesting that `var_dump` or `print_r` would be better ways of going about doing what `implode` would do.